# Is there anything I did wrong and can improve with this program?

Tags: python, function, conditional-statements

I am taking an online course on Edx by microsoft. On one assignment, I have to make a program about ordering cheese. I did everything they asked, and the program works, but I want to see what I can do to improve the code I wrote.

Here are some steps they provided:

- set values for maximum and minimum order variables
- set value for price variable
- get order_amount input and cast to a number
- check order_amount and give message checking against

  - over maximum
  - under minimum
- else within maximum and minimum give message with calculated price

Here are some examples they also provided:
Sample input and output:

```
>>>Enter cheese order weight (numeric value): 113
113.0 is more than currently available stock
>>>Enter cheese order weight (numeric value): .15
0.15 is below minimum order amount
>>>Enter cheese order weight (numeric value): 2
2.0 costs $15.98
```

This is all I can come up with and I want to find out a way to not have to put float() on every order_amount. Is there some other way to do it?

```
maximum_order = 100.0
minimum_order = 1.0

def cheese_program(order_amount):

    if order_amount.isdigit() == False:
        print('Enter numeric value')

    elif float(order_amount) > maximum_order:
        print(order_amount, "is more than currently available stock")

    elif float(order_amount) < minimum_order:
        print(order_amount, "is less than currently available stock")

    elif (float(order_amount) <= maximum_order) and (float(order_amount) >= minimum_order):
        print(order_amount, "pounds costs", "$", int(order_amount) * 5)

    else:
        print("Enter numeric value")


weight = input("Enter cheese order weight (pounds numeric value): ")
function = cheese_program(weight)
```

Answer (score 3):

this is a variant:

```
def cheese_program(order_amount):

    try:
        order_amount = float(order_amount)
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter numeric value")
        return

    if order_amount > maximum_order:
        print(order_amount, "is more than currently available stock")
    elif order_amount < minimum_order:
        print(order_amount, "is less than currently available stock")
    else:
        print(order_amount, "pounds costs", "$", int(order_amount) * 5)
```

converting to `float` once and returning directly if that can't be done. and simplified the conditions a bit.

if you are using python >= 3.6 you could also write those print statements a bit more elegantly - e.g.:

```
print(f"{order_amount} pounds costs ${int(order_amount) * 5}")
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of comments.  Maybe you were just focusing on the python, but just in case, this might save you a couple of points on your assignment :-):

- Your output does not match the examples you gave.  The example error for less than is "that is below the minimum order" but yours says "that is less than what is currently available in stock"
- Your code coerces the value to an int, but the answer is a float ($15.98).
- You have `function = cheese_program(weight)` but cheese_program does not return a value.

It looks like you are early in your class so probably have not gotten to classes yet, but here is a reference for later:

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/user-defined-exception

As shown in the link, you could create "ValueTooLargeError" and "ValueTooSmallError" user exceptions and then call your function something like `order_cost = calculate_order_cost(order_amount)` with no prints in that function.  It then either returns the cost or throws an exception and you can react appropriately, something like:

```
try:
    print(order_amount,"costs $", calculate_order_cost(order_amount))
except ValueError:
    print("Order amount must be a numeric value")
except ValueTooLargeError:
    print(order_amount,"is greater than our current stock")
except ValueTooSmallError:
    print(order_amount, "is less than the minimum order allowed.")
except:
    print("unknown exception")
```

or more concisely:

```
try:
    print(order_amount,"costs $", order_cost)
except ValueError, ValueTooLargeError, ValueTooSmallError:
    print("Order amount must be a numeric value between", minimum_order, "and ", maximum_order)
except:
    print("unknown exeption")
```

That way your code is behaving along the same lines as the float() function.  If it finds an error, it just raises an exception and lets the caller decide what to do with it.

Hope that helps and good luck with your class.